# send additional strings to Event handler function

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

i have a standard mouseEventHandler :

`a.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(labelClick);`

where a is a label. the function called on click is like so :

```
private void labelClick(object sender,MouseEventArgs mea)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("click on the label");
        }
```

How can i send more information to the called function? (i.e. i have a lot of labels ; for each label i would like to send 2 strings for my location and address )

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.MouseClick += (sender, e) => HandleLabelMouseClick(sender, e, "whatever1", "whatever2");

private void HandleLabelMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, string whatever1, string whatever2)
{
    MessageBox.Show(whatever1 + "\n" + whatever2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the Tag property of the label and cast the sender parameter as a label and read the Tag property.

Set the Tag property to the

```
string.Format("{0};{1}", Location, Address)
```

Then in the event handler

```
Label lbl = sender as Label;
String[] LocAdd = ((String)lbl.Tag).Split(';');
```

Now you have the Location in the first item in the array and the Address in the second one.